# Getting error "Package org.eclipse.... does not exist" in Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I cloned a Git repository and opened the project in Intellij. The project has a Maven build, and Intellij has Eclipse integration enabled. However, it seems that Intellij is not able to import some of the Eclipse-specific packages.

Below is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Is this happening because Intellij does not support EMF (Eclipse modeling framework)? Is there something that can be done about it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can download the EMF related jar files from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mod4j.org.eclipse.emf

Comment: Thank you! I did this, and it worked for almost all of the classes. However, some of the classes still appear to not be working (are not able to be imported). Will try to find JAR's for those as well.

Comment: Great. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Import the project to IDEA as a maven project, once the project is loaded, configure the maven settings in IDEA (point to the maven installation,check whether it picked the correct Local repository path and setting xml), if auto import is disabled , then IDEA will prompt you to re-import the project changes, click to re-import the changes. wait until all dependencies are downloaded to local repo.